# long polling doesn't stop

Tags: php, mysql, long-integer, polling

I tried to modified the long polling code to fit my situation.
I would like to count the total number from mysql and if the number changes (increase or decrease), it will notify me.

The problem is the while loop keep looping.  How can I stop it?  I just need to have notification whenever the total sum change.

```
<?php
include("db.php");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT sum( r ) as totalsum FROM (SELECT colA, colB, COUNT( * ) AS r FROM product GROUP BY productid ) AS t");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $old_totalsum = $row['totalsum']; 
}

?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var old_totalsum =<?php echo $old_totalsum; ?>;
function waitForMsg(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "poll.php?old_totalsum=" + old_totalsum,
    async: true,
    cache: false,
        success: function(data){

        var json = "eval(+(" + data + ")+)";
    if(json['msg'] != "") {

        alert(data); 
    }

    old_msg_id = json['old_msg_id']; 
    setTimeout('waitForMsg()',1000);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert("error: " + textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
    setTimeout('waitForMsg()',15000);
    }


    });  // end ajax
} //end waitformsg


$(document).ready(function(){ 
 waitForMsg();
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chat">
</div>
</body>
</html>
<----------------------------------------------------------->

poll.php
<----------------------------------------------------------->
<?php
include("db.php");

$old_totalsum = $_GET['old_totalsum']; 


$result = mysql_query("SELECT sum( r ) as totalsum FROM (SELECT colA, colB, COUNT( * ) AS r FROM product GROUP BY productid ) AS t");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $last_sum = $row['totalsum']; 
}



while($last_sum < $old_totalsum || $last_sum > $old_totalsum)


    while($last_sum <= $old_totalsum)
    {
    usleep(1000);
    clearstatcache();
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT sum( r ) as totalsum FROM (SELECT colA, colB, COUNT( * ) AS r FROM product GROUP BY productid ) AS t");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
         $last_sum = $row['totalsum'];
            //echo $last_sum;
            //return;
        }

    }





$response = array();
$response['msg'] = 'new';
$response['old_msg_id'] = $last_sum;
echo json_encode($response);
?>
<------------------------------------------->
```

Comment: Which `while` loop doesn't exit? The `while($last_sum <= $old_totalsum)` or the `while($last_sum < $old_totalsum || $last_sum > $old_totalsum)`

Comment: oh sorry no while($last_sum <= $old_totalsum) .... sorry to confuse you since I am testing different condition

Comment: while($last_sum <= $old_totalsum) ... if the inserts keep increasing the loop won't end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expected logic like this:

```
$latest_sum= -1;
// Loop until sum from DB is different from what was passed  in
while( $latest_sum == -1 || $latest_sum!= $old_sum ){
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT sum( r ) as totalsum FROM (SELECT colA, colB, COUNT( * ) AS r FROM product GROUP BY productid ) AS t");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
      $lastest_sum = $row['totalsum']; 
   }
}

$response = array();
$response['msg'] = 'new';
$response['old_msg_id'] = $latest_sum;
echo json_encode($response);
```

If it takes a long time to change, then Apache (or whatever is running PHP) will likely cancel the request. This is also going to run lots of queries on the db which is expensive.

So it would be better to have your loop in the javascript.  It would call a function that would just return the latest sum from the database.  The javascript should wait a second or more inbetween each request.

If performance is still too hard on the database, then the php should somehow cache the value every minute and return the cached value.

Comment: may I ask a question first before I test your approach.

Comment: why while($last_sum < $old_totalsum || $last_sum > $old_totalsum) cannot exit?  I assume the $last_sum will be updated and cause this condition break.

Comment: Dave where should I put your code?  I see you put $latest_sum= -1; and this will cause you the while loop always true, isn't it?  then it means it will keep looping as well?

Comment: oh..I just test again, seems the condition is ok.  BUT when I run in index.php, it now keep showing me a popup box which from line if(json['msg'] != "") {

        alert(data); 
    }

Comment: now the situation is reversed.  if I change database to make the number bigger or smaller, it doesn't show me a popup.  If I do nothing and the number is the same, it keep popup!!  So, how can I reverse this situation???

Comment: I updated my code.  I still think your approach is wrong.  The php code should not have a while loop.  It should just return the latest count from the database.  Your javascript will then compare against the last value and decide if it should alert.  Does that make sense?

Comment: sorry..should I copy only you code into poll.php?  or I need to keep some portion?

Comment: ok just run your code from index.php.  then nothing happen, so I try try modify mysql and change the value, still nothing happen.

Comment: What do you see if you call poll.php directly (passing it the correct query parameters)

Comment: hi,  finally I set while(($last_sum == $old_totalsum) )  it will keep looping until the total sum change, it will break and update the numbers!  many thanks